# Como montar uma query com condições opcionais?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, array, query

No exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM exemplo WHERE ID in(2, 3, 4)
```

Ele traz se tiver esses `ID` no banco.

Como montar uma *query* que coloque esta condição apenas se o *array* no PHP tiver elementos?

PHP:

```
$id= implode(', ', $_GET['id']);
$nome= implode(', ', $_GET['nome']);
$cidade= implode(', ', $_GET['cidade']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM EXEMPLO WHERE id IN($id) AND nome IN($nome) AND cidade IN($cidade)");

//Se tiver de acordo com a condição traz a linha dentro da condição, se não traz todas as linhas.
```

Eu tentei assim, mas não sei se é correto;

```
$id= "(id='".implode("' OR id='", $_GET['id'])."') AND";
$nome= "(nome='".implode("' OR nome='", $_GET['nome'])."') AND";
$cidade= "(cidade='".implode("' OR cidade='", $_GET['cidade'])."')";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM EXEMPLO WHERE $id $nome $cidade");
```

Comment: A hora que você terminar de mudar o problema, você me avisa e eu tento responder direito. Cada hora que eu acerto a resposta você muda alguma coisa.

Comment: Falta o `")`na última linha.

Comment: Sim esqueci de digitar aqui rs..

Comment: Cara esse implode, só vai funcionar se vc tiver um array com as IDs nesse $_GET['id']; tipo $get_data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6); implode(', ', $get_data);

Comment: Sim eu uso varios inputs com o name="id[]", isso faz com que envie via get um array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Melhor resolver no PHP e analisar se o *array* é vazio ou não. Se for vazio, traga tudo, se não for, use a condição. Depois das várias mudanças na formulação, de acordo com os comentários eu faria algo assim:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM exemplo WHERE TRUE";
if (!empty($condicao1)) {
    $lista = implode(",", $condicao1);
    $query .= " AND ID NOT IN ($lista)";
}
if (!empty($condicao2)) {
    $lista = implode(",", $condicao2);
    $query .= " AND NOME NOT IN ($lista)";
}
if (!empty($condicao3)) {
    $lista = implode(",", $condicao3);
    $query .= " AND CIDADE NOT IN ($lista)";
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/BuildQuery.php).

Coloquei `echo` só para ilustrar, use no PDO da forma como achar melhor. É claro que se tivesse o código, eu soubesse a situação real, poderia ajudar mais, mas abstratamente é isto. Em situação concreta eu sofisticaria isto.

Esta técnica pode ser usada para montar qualquer tipo de condição.

Comment: Mas ai ele não vai trazer esses ids.

Comment: Ah, você quer que ele procure por esses, se não achar nada, então deve trazer tudo, é isto? SE for isto, eu acho que só com um `SELECT` não consegue, precisaria pensar. Conforme for eu vou apagar e se der tempo de achar uma solução, eu posto. Até pensei em uma solução simples com `SELECT` mas ela é porca, eu só usaria se não achasse outra melhor.

Comment: Assim, eu recebo uma array com vários ids, ai eu uso o implode para separar, e uso em um IN, mas quero que quando o array estiver vazia, traga todos os resultados sem o filtro.

Comment: Ok, Obrigado ^^

Comment: Teria sido melhor ter colocado seu código PHP que gera esse *array* para ter uma noção melhor do que está fazendo. Eu acho que neste caso  é melhor resolver pelo PHP.

Comment: Eu não vou usar somente um IN, se não eu usava o if do php para separar, ia ser mais ou menos assim:

SELECT * FROM exemplo WHERE ID IN($codicao1)  AND nome IN($codicao2)  AND cidade IN($codicao3)

Comment: Bom, sua pergunta já mudou completamente do que você escreveu originalmente, né? Mas ainda faria desta forma, só seria um `if` mais complexo, teria que ir construindo a *string*.

Comment: Pronto editei  a pergunta ve lá se você entende melhor!

Comment: Eu usei de outro modo ve lá editei, só ve se vc acha correto! Pois desse meu modo ele pode receber mais de uma cidade também, nesse seu if ele só recebe uma!

Comment: Não está correto, isto nem executa. E nem falei da falha de segurança que tem neste código mas isto é outro assunto.

Comment: Eu já tentei isso e da certo sim, as falhas eu já tratei tirando todas as letras e acentos com o e ereg_raplace. Só queria saber se tinha algo mais simples de usar, pois ache o código meio grande.

Comment: Se você diz que deu certo, vai fundo. Dá em certas circunstâncias, se você pode garantir que elas sempre estarão presentes, ótimo. Se não pode, você é que terá problemas.

Comment: Então pelos testes que fiz deu certo, não passa letra e nem acentos somente números que seria ids. Vamos ver quando o usuário for usar, pois é o unico que consegue realmente fazer um teste completo rsrsrs.